# Behavior of GridView in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am having a `GridView` and added more than 50 images on it and performing delete operation on them.

I observe that what images i am deleting,they are leaving the blank space from top, means other images are not taking that place which is look so ugly.

I want that deleting image space should be covered by other images in grid.

Thanks.

code

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.delete_button)
        {
            adp.list.removeAll(bitmapList);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            bitmapList.clear();
            grid.clearChoices();



        }
```

Comment: How do you delete images?

Comment: from list and notify the adapter

Comment: can you paste some code ?

Answer (score 0):

after every image you delete try to reload grid view by calling notifydatasetchanged on adapter this will help [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: i am using this adp.notifyDataSetChanged();